# Big Query: Why are table previews no longer available after August 5, 2014?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a process that generates new tables every day. I used to be able to preview the tables to see the first five rows of the table. I can still do so, but only for tables created on or before August 5, 2014. The newer tables show the message:

Preview is not currently available for this table.

I have made no changes to my processes that could explain this change.

Is there a problem? Are previews just delayed now? Or, is the preview feature going away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried both accessing sample datasets an creating a new table with sample data and in both cases I could see table preview.

Do you still have this issue? Maybe there could be some delay to access preview after creating large tables.

Regards
Paolo

Comment: I'm still seeing it on my tables. They're 500,000,000 row tables, by the way. They have been 500M row daily tables since I started about three months ago. This inability to see the previews is something I noticed beginning on August 5th.

Answer (score 2):

I have noticed that if a table is loaded as EXTERNAL (happened to me when I by hand load in a table with the UI from google drive) it does not show "preview" option. This makes some sense, if you think of it, Since the BigQuery knows there is a file somewhere else where-to the table is linked... saying perhaps: go look at it there.  (in this case for instance I am able to switch a value in my google sheet and, without running any function, it updates in bigquery).

When I loaded the tables through a csv upload script only - they show up with 'preview' and also seem unlinked from their original upload files.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen simply because the table is empty. I kept hitting reload and seeing it. The moment the table had data, it showed up.